# Zen Cart Vs Magento

Tags: php, magento, zen-cart

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Zen Cart and Magento?
Plz list the scenarios in which i should prefer one of them?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in practice, I've only used Magento, but before using ecommerce platform, I've reviewed many of them.

First about Zen Cart. When started in 2003, it was only a fork of osCommerce. Since then, core has been significantly changed, and since v1.3 it also features a whole new template system. I'd suggest using ZenCart over osCommerce, if you ever look that way. Now comparing it against Magento, I'd say choose Zen Cart if you need more lightweight store. I'm not saying you cannot do more advanced things with it, but I believe you will need to do much more core-digging if you want to customize it to your specific needs. Which also means you can quickly break something or in the worst case, it'll break the system when you update the core.

Now to Magento. It's huge. And I mean it. Definitely not easy to learn, and in the start difficult to work with, but very well engineered, and when you get used to it, you find there is so much configuration options and if you really need to change some core parts, you can easily override models/blocks/helpers/etc, which means you remain update-safe. Worst case is, your module will break, but not the core. 
Also, its layout system, at least to me, seems powerful and easy to learn, although you need a few days to get around with it.

Also, Magento offers multiple stores and store views, and is therefore much more customizable. However, the power comes with a cost - cost of complexity and speed. Magento is not the fastest thing in the world, I'd say quite otherwise - I haven't seen bigger and resource-consuming app writen in PHP. If you do not have your own server or VPS, don't even think about it. It will not work good on shared hosting. There is another glitch - almost no docs. You'll find some articles, but problem is they are mostly outdated. Community is active and helps, but if you got stuck in a problem you cannot google-out, you're practically stuck on your own.

Bottom line, if you've got the nerves, time and money, investing into Magento pays off. It is a beast in every mean and I haven't found a thing that couldn't be done with it. Otherwise don't bother with it and choose Zen Cart or something else.

Comment: Magento requires powered, self balancing training wheels. You will need to run it on a dedicated system, split servers best. It runs as fast as the horsepower and optimization you throw at it. I'd recommend Tiny Brick's LightSpeed page cache as well. The less Magento's involved in creating and serving the pages, the better the performance. Feature rich and extensible, but slightly ahead of its time as to hardware requirements, kind of like my first introduction to Xwindows.